# Is threre any way to ues override method in anonymous class on Groovy @CompileStatic annotation

Tags: groovy

Is threre any way to ues override method in anonymous class on Groovy @CompileStatic annotation?

groogy source

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic;
interface HelloWorld {
    public void greet();
}

class HelloWorldAnonymousClassesParents {
    public void hi() {
        println "hi"
    }
}

@CompileStatic
public class HelloWorldAnonymousClasses extends HelloWorldAnonymousClassesParents {
    public void hi() {
        System.out.println("hihi ");
    }
    public void sayHello() {
        HelloWorld spanishGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
            public void greet() {
                hi() //<- here [Static type checking] - Reference to method is ambiguous error
                System.out.println("spanishGreeting");
            }
        };
        spanishGreeting.greet();
        hi()
    }

}
def myApp = new HelloWorldAnonymousClasses();
myApp.sayHello();
```

Same source in java run well

java source

```
package org.octopus;


class HelloWorldAnonymousClassesParents {
    public void hi() {
        System.out.println("hi ");
    }
}

interface HelloWorld {
    public void greet();
}

public class Test extends HelloWorldAnonymousClassesParents{

    public void hi() {
        System.out.println("hihi ");
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        HelloWorld spanishGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
            public void greet() {
                hi(); 
                System.out.println("spanishGreeting");
            }
        };
        spanishGreeting.greet();
        hi();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Test myApp = new Test();
        myApp.sayHello();
    }            
}
```

How can I avoid that error with @CompileStatic annotation?

Comment: It's a bug. I have created a ticket for it: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6882

Comment: Thank you for reporting groovy jira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it as a closure.  This implies an `as HelloWorld` and as the interface only has one method groovy can deduct this.

```
            HelloWorld spanishGreeting = {
                    hi() 
                    System.out.println("spanishGreeting");
            }
```

above code is groovy 2.3; with earlier groovy 2 versions it needs an explicit cast like

```
def spanishGreeting = {/*...*/} as HelloWorld
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But 
spanishGreeting become closure. So GroovyCastException occured.
Is there any code that have to add to avoid GroovyCastException?

Comment: above code is groovy 2.3; with groovy 2.2 it might work with an explicit cast like ``def spanishGreeting = {/*...*/} as HelloWorld``

Comment: def spanishGreeting = {/*...*/} as HelloWorld code works at groovy 2.1. Thank you for your help.